# Error while running a python script in Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have installed Anaconda (Python 2.7) in Windows 7. Initially, it was a bit problematic to start spyder, but eventually I figured out that by running cmd as administrator, spyder starts. As soon as I ran my first python script in Spyder, it showed me an error in its internal console:

```
 F:\PythonIDE\lib\site-packages\nbformat\current.py:19: UserWarning: nbformat.current is deprecated.

- use nbformat for read/write/validate public API
- use nbformat.vX directly to composing notebooks of a particular version

  """)
F:\PythonIDE\lib\pkgutil.py:110: FutureWarning: The pandas.rpy module is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. We refer to external packages like rpy2. 
See here for a guide on how to port your code to rpy2: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html
  __import__(name)
F:\PythonIDE\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py:137: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The matplotlib.delaunay module was deprecated in version 1.4. Use matplotlib.tri.Triangulation instead.
  warnings.warn(message, mplDeprecation, stacklevel=1)
F:\PythonIDE\lib\site-packages\skimage\filter\__init__.py:6: skimage_deprecation: The `skimage.filter` module has been renamed to `skimage.filters`.  This placeholder module will be removed in v0.13.
  warn(skimage_deprecation('The `skimage.filter` module has been renamed '
Failed to write user configuration file.
Please submit a bug report.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\PythonIDE\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\plugins\editor.py", line 2066, in run_file
    dialog.setup(fname)
  File "F:\PythonIDE\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\plugins\runconfig.py", line 349, in setup
    self.runconfigoptions = RunConfigOptions(self)
  File "F:\PythonIDE\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\plugins\runconfig.py", line 148, in __init__
    self.runconf = RunConfiguration()
  File "F:\PythonIDE\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\plugins\runconfig.py", line 57, in __init__
    self.set(CONF.get('run', 'defaultconfiguration', default={}))
  File "F:\PythonIDE\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\userconfig.py", line 387, in get
    self.set(section, option, default)
  File "F:\PythonIDE\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\userconfig.py", line 446, in set
    self._save()
  File "F:\PythonIDE\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\userconfig.py", line 136, in _save
    raise(e)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: u'C:\\Users\\Shubhanshu\\.spyder2\\spyder.ini'
```

Now, how to rectify this error? I would be really grateful for any help in this regard.

Comment: it seems that you don't have the rights to access that file. Maybe is read only.

Comment: I suppose, by file you meant the script that I am trying to run? If that's the case, then no. It's a normal python script and I have all the access for that file.

Comment: No, I'm referring to `spyder.ini`.

Comment: So, how do I deal with spyder.ini being read-only? Is there any way to fix that, such that my script runs?